# Handle Ajax Uploads with a Managed Bean in JQuery and Java

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

Here is the scope :
- Jquery DropzoneJS : User puts a file but is not processed till submit with (`autoProcessQueue: true`)
- On submit the file should be uploaded

What I reached till now :
Here is my Bean Upload :

```
 public void fileUpload() throws  IOException {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest )context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)context.getExternalContext().getResponse();
       if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Request is not multipart, please 'multipart/form-data' enctype for your form.");
       }

       ServletFileUpload uploadHandler = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory());
       PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

       System.out.println(new File("C:/Users/ceo/Pictures/Saved Pictures/" + "images/"));
       try {
           List<FileItem> items = uploadHandler.parseRequest(request);

           for (FileItem item : items) {
               if (!item.isFormField()) {
                   SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
                   String name = fmt.format(new Date()) + item.getName();

                       File file = new File("C:/Users/ceo/Pictures/Saved Pictures/uploads/images/", name);
                       item.write(file);
                       imagepath = "/uploads/images/" + name;

                       System.out.println("uploaded");
                       this.setImagepath(imagepath);
               }
           }
       } catch (FileUploadException e) {
               throw new RuntimeException(e);
       } catch (Exception e) {
               throw new RuntimeException(e);
       } finally {

           writer.close();
       }


    }
```

Which is called from :

```
$(document)
                .ready(
                        function() {
                            var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#upload", {
                                url : "#{usermanagerMB.fileUpload()}",
                                autoProcessQueue: true,
                                method : "post",
                                maxFiles : 1,
                                uploadMultiple: false,
                                maxfilesexceeded : function(file) {
                                    this.removeAllFiles();
                                    this.addFile(file);
                                },
                                error: function (file, response) {
                                file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-error");
                                }
                            });
```

As this is on the first page, simply running the project gives me :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request is not multipart, please 'multipart/form-data' enctype for your form.
    at empsuite.managedbean.UsermanagerManagedBean.fileUpload(UsermanagerManagedBean.java:231)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:165)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:84)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:157)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:238)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.writeText(ELText.java:154)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:85)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    ... 22 more
```

What I need to know :
- Why does this happen while I didn't even chose any file or did any action ?
- How to make the bean upload the file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using omnifaces ajax handler this is done easily (ajax.oncomplete)